# Altering value of CSS property with calculated variable via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables, properties

I'm trying to set a value of a css property with a calculated variable value.

I have two classes `.v-table__overflow` and `.v-datatable__actions`. I want to get the width value of `.v-table__overflow` and set this value in `.v-datatable__actions` as the value of width of this class.

I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setProperty' of undefined

```
var dtoverflow = document.querySelector('.v-table__overflow')
const style4 =  getComputedStyle(dtoverflow);
var dtoverflowWidth = style4.width 

var dtActions = document.querySelector('.v-datatable__actions') 
const style5 =  getComputedStyle(dtActions); 
var dtActionsWidth = style5.width;

dtActionsWidth.style.setProperty('width', '--dtoverflowWidth');
```

Comment: It looks like `dtActionsWidth` is the `width` value from the computed styles of `dtActions`. The variable `dtActionsWidth` has no [`style` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style). Maybe you want `dtActions.style.setProperty(...)`?

Comment: its a vuetiify app - using a vue.js framework for frontend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
var dtoverflow = document.querySelector('.v-table__overflow')
var dtoverflowWidth = getComputedStyle(dtoverflow).width;

var dtActions = document.querySelector('.v-datatable__actions') 
var dtActionsWidth = getComputedStyle(dtActions).width;

dtActions.style.width = dtoverflowWidth;
```

You also had a typo with using `dtActionsWidth` instead of `dtActions` in the last line which threw the error.

Comment: @showdev The code had a typo with using `dtActionsWidth` instead of `dtActions` in the last line which threw the error.